# HBaseClient: The znode for the -ROOT- region doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, hbase, opentsdb

I followed instruction to set up OpenTSDB: http://opentsdb.net/getting-started.html and http://opentsdb.net/setup-hbase.html. After I start opentsdb using command:

```
./build/tsdb tsd --port=80 --staticroot=/opt/opentsdb/build/staticroot --cachedir=/tmp/tsd
```

I got following errors:

**`2013-10-04 22:59:40,577 ERROR [main-EventThread] HBaseClient: The znode for the -ROOT- region doesn't exist!`**

here is the log files from hbase:

```
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:51:40,045 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90001 type:create cxid:0x8 zxid:0x10 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/online-snapshot Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/online-snapshot
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:51:40,070 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90000 type:create cxid:0x24 zxid:0x15 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/online-snapshot/acquired Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/online-snapshot/acquired
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:51:45,798 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90000 type:delete cxid:0x3c zxid:0x17 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/meta-region-server Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/meta-region-server
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:51:46,419 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90000 type:create cxid:0x5b zxid:0x1f txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table-lock/hbase:namespace Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/table-lock/hbase:namespace
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:51:47,063 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90000 type:create cxid:0x7a zxid:0x2f txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/namespace/default Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/namespace/default
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:51:47,074 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90000 type:create cxid:0x7e zxid:0x31 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/namespace/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/namespace/hbase
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:54:42,588 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90000 type:create cxid:0xa5 zxid:0x39 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table-lock/tsdb-uid Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/table-lock/tsdb-uid
hbase-root-master-ip-10-158-96-233.log:2013-10-04 22:54:43,416 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14185ab2dc90000 type:create cxid:0xbd zxid:0x44 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table-lock/tsdb Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/table-lock/tsdb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I reported this issue, I found out that when I used HBASE version 0.94.12, I don't see this issue. But when I used latest HBase version 0.96.0, I started seeing installation errors. I switched to use HBase stable version which is 0.94.12 for now.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem. I fixed this with changing my */etc/hosts* file. It probably looks like this:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1 hostname

change this to:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1 hostname

Here some more info
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html at 1.2 Quick Start

Answer (score 0):

This means that OpenTSDB's HBase client is unable to locate the `-ROOT-` region of HBase because there is no "file" (znode) in ZooKeeper to indicate where it is.  This is most likely caused by HBase not running, or died upon starting due to some problem.  Check the `logs` directory in your HBase root directory, you will probably find what the root cause is in HBase's log file.

Comment: Thanks @tsuna, I'm looking logs directory to see what I can find out.